# No option to move blocks up and down. The bar for it simply isn't there

Tags: menus

I make my website in Astra and I can't find the "move block" bar. I have tried a lot of things like uninstalling and installing astra again. I can show you the picture where there should be a move block bar but it isn't there.

[image: From my website]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a black background. Change the background color and the move block bar will be visible.